# Do these sounds and messages indicate a dead hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

Last week my HDD apparently died. I could neither boot nor even read it when booting a live debian distro. When powering up the HDD, it makes the following sound:

- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjYARtEfuKgR3VVQUdrSVZCZXc
- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjYARtEfuKgWWxSQlk4c3BwaHM

I also tried to connect it as an external HDD and `dmesg` reported the following:

```
[114817.677736] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[114817.807355] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[114817.807361] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[114817.807364] usb 1-2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[114817.807366] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[114817.807368] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 152D203380B6
[114817.808377] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[114817.808568] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[114818.806902] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access                                    PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[114818.807114] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[114818.808349] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[114818.808787] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[114818.808790] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[114818.811560] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

I even tried `dd if=/dev/sdc of=./sample bs=100M count=1` to see if I could read anything, but the resulting file was completely empty. Needless to say, no partitions are recognized at all and I cannot even format it.

Are these indicating a dead hard drive or is there any hope of being able to retrieve anything from it? Thankfully, I don't have anything of high importance to be retrieved.

The HDD was a 1000GB Seagate, bought in 2012.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the "[click of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death#Hard_disk_drives)".

Aside from the off-chance it may start working if the drive electronics are replaced with a PCB from an IDENTICAL drive, the drive is dead -- replace it.

Some related SU questions you may want to check out:

- [What is causing my hard drive's click of death?](https://superuser.com/questions/95218/what-is-causing-my-hard-drives-click-of-death?rq=1)
- [Click of death - freeze or replace PCB?](https://superuser.com/questions/980227/click-of-death-freeze-or-replace-pcb)
- [Can a "click of death" from one drive cause an SMI (system management interrupt) or similar?](https://superuser.com/questions/857160/can-a-click-of-death-from-one-drive-cause-an-smi-system-management-interrupt?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Upvote.  I always like to say that hard drives are like light bulbs:  Whenever you turn one on be ready to say goodbye.  But for me that's just a minor annoyance because I keep good backups.  Another thing I like to say is that the best backup for a hard drive is another hard drive.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thank you very much for the answer and the links, I actually wanted additional information to get insight understanding. :)